# google map v3 zoom controls not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, controls, zooming

I am not seeing any reason why the zoom controls are not showing up as the controls are not disabled in my option? this is v3 google map..has anyone faced similar issue? I can zoom in and out using mouse scroll button or touchpad scroll of laptop..but the icons +/- would be great!

```
var geocoder;
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.095287, -79.3185139);
    var myOptions = {
        maxZoom: 12,
      //zoom: 9,
      //center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
   }
```

Comment: What happens if you use both zoom: 9 and also maxZoom: 12 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use zoom and also center properties to display your map correctly, here is a  jsfiddle of a map constructed with your options.
http://jsfiddle.net/5ytkx/9/

Remove the comments before zoom and center properties

```
 zoom: 9,
 center: latlng,
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The answer was different, but you lit that light in my brain! I compared the css between your fiddle and my Sharepoint page, where the map was embedded on..a css class .gmnoprint{display:none !important;} was the culprit! No wonder all the controls were gone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because your `myOptions` variable includes a trailing comma?

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
```

Will it work if you remove that?

Hope this helps

Comment: I deleted the comma, map displays fine, still no controls! :(

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId['ROADMAP']
```